# Modify custom field from front end

Tags: custom-field, post-meta, front-end

If I need to manage a custom field under wordpress, but not from the admin area. In other words, I need that users modify the content of post custom fields from front end. What is the way to do so?

As instance, please to imagine Stackexchange.com as a wordpress site. Under this site, the the accept state is my post custom field. How can I make the front end user modify its value in WP database?

Please If you have another better approach to create accept system, using wordpress, it will be highly appreciated. But if my approach (using post custom field) is okey, please to guide me find documentation from web or codex to achieve my goal.

Thank you for your usual help.

Comment: This is a very broad question and similar things have been asked on this site. [Search](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=front+end+post) and see if you can get started, then [edit] the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to update custom field.

You can use:

```
global $post;
update_post_meta($post->ID, $meta_key, $meta_value);
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta